# React handling Form Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, components, react-props

Alright I am trying to submit two different forms as independent components in another page 
component where I only have one button to submit the data of both forms. 
So I am struggling to have a shared state in the page component and I need to pass the whole state of each form component to my page component on submit.
Can anyone recommend a best practice for my use case ?

```
render() {
    return (
      <div as={Row} className="container" style={formStyle}>
        <Col>
          <Form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
            <TripForm />
            <PostForm heading="add your first blog entry" />
            <Button variant="dark" type="submit">
              Summing up
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Col>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest on Blur of every field you get the full state of that form into this component by passing a function as a prop and then submit the data when submit is clicked

Answer (score 1):

define your state in the parent component and pass it down in props

```
class PageComponent = {

  state = { } //define your state here

  handleChange = () => {} // define a function that handles changing state

  submitData = () => {
    // in here you can access this.state and then submit form data with that state
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div as={Row} className="container" style={formStyle}>
        <Col>
          <Form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
            <TripForm handleChange={handleChange} someState={someState} />
            <PostForm heading="add your first blog entry" handleChange={handleChange} someState={someState}/>
            <Button variant="dark" type="submit">
              Summing up
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Col>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I've also defined `someState` which you can pass down as props to the child/form components. once you set state in there with `handleChange` it will set state in the parent component and you can `submitData` with that state